# Application Pool Start and Manage Website Start each start their own instance - Why?

Tags: iis-10, asp.net-core-5.0

When I start the application pool, it starts an instance of the code of my website, even though the website is not "started" under sites.

When I start the site, I get a second run of the site.

My question is why? And do I need to start both, or just one of them?  If both, can I stop two instances executing?

I have a worker instance attached to my Web API which collects data, and doing this twice within a very short timeframe is not desirable.

**EDIT** For clarification:

This is my Program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                _ = webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                _ = services.AddHostedService<MyWorker>().Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                    {
                        config.LogName = "My API";
                        config.SourceName = "My API";
                    });
            });

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            InitialiseGlobals();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToEventLog(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the Application Pool, the code in the MyWorker Class executes. I know this because the logs show it is running.

When I start the site under sites, the logs show it running the method in the MyWorker class again.

Ideally, it should only start one instance.

IIS Settings

```
Application Pool:
Name = DotNetCore
Start Mode = AlwaysRunning
NET CLR Version = No Managed Code
Managed Pipeline Mode = Integrated
Idle Time-out (minutes) = 0

Website
Site name = MyApi
Application pool = DotNetCore
Binding
Type = https
IP address = All Unassigned
Port = 4443
```

Comment: "it starts an instance of the code of my website" - what makes you think that? And exactly **what** code are you referring to? Your ASP.NET Core Program's `Main` method? and/or an actual (but synthetic) incoming HTTP request?

Comment: "I get a second run of the site." - again, please clarify **exactly** what you're seeing - are you seeing a second instance of your application's `.exe` running as a new process? What IIS settings are you using? Have you considered in-proc hosting? Are you using any web-farm settings? Etc

Comment: "I have a worker instance attached to my Web API" - what exactly do you mean by "worker instance"? is that a separate executable? a separate `IHost` instance in the same process? (also, IIS is not a good way to run non-webserver headless applications on Windows, you should use a Windows Service instead)

Comment: @Dai added clarification

Comment: I suggest you set a breakpoint in your `Main` method and check all of the environment-variables (and other ASP.NET Core stuff it gets from the ASP.NET Core IIS ISAPI add-in) as that will give you some hints. I'm curious to find out why too, but I don't have IIS installed right now so I can't try to reproduce your issue at my end.

Comment: Debugging it doesn't do it. I notice that if I start the site, then the application pool second, it only has the one iteration going.

Comment: Have you considered host model of core application on IIS? What host model you used and have changed it? If it is out of process, IIS just a proxy to forward request, maybe application never stop in kesterl.

Comment: @BruceZhang this is when I'm just adding it for the first time.  If I start the pool before the site, I get two instances.  If I do it reverse I only get one.  I have completely removed and rebuilt both the site and the pool numerous times, but doing it in that order is the only thing that seems to stop it.